# Is the AES-GCM in Python Crypto.Cipher library can take care the AAD portion

Tags: python, encryption, aes-gcm

Looking at the description below, it doesn't looks like the AES-GCM mode in Crypto. Cipher library  can take in AAD data. Do we need to handle it separately for using this? Can advise if my understanding is correct. How to achieve the AES-GCM encryption with using this library if I have the AAD portion in my content need to be take care?

[image]

Comment: The AAD are generally passed in PyCryptodome with [`update()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#update), s. also this [example](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#gcm-mode).

Comment: PyCrypto is abandoned, use alternatives like pyca/cryptography https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/aead/#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers.aead.AESGCM

Comment: @frost-nzcr4 - OP uses _PyCryptodome_ and not legacy _PyCrypto_, at least according to the posted documentation excerpt. So there's actually no reason to recommend a change (especially since library recommendations are off-topic on SO).

Comment: Ok, my fault, but at least question should provide proper library name. And second, recommendations in answer with the actual libraries that can help with encryption isn't the same as question asking recommendations to ignite the flamewar.

Answer (score 1):

As Topaco said in comment, use [update()](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#update). For example:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
nonce = bytes(12)
data = bytes(0)
ad = bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
cipher.update(ad)
ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(data)
```